# Add a contact community tool for Moderators?

Tags: feature-request, moderator-tools

Fairly often we as moderators need to contact the community (employee) team through e-mail for something or another, most recently disassociating a user's post.  Currently we e-mail community@stackexchange.com and if we remember to cc our fellow mods.

It would be better if we had a moderator tool that sent an e-mail to the user and notified our fellow mods similar to how they are for a mod message to a user.

Comment: Easy! Just suspend someone! (Don't)

Comment: Would a chat room maybe work for this? I mean, as a simple work-around, if you can lock it to only the people you want, that is.

Comment: Not everybody can use chat.

Comment: @M.NightDemonbobby - A chat room is not ideal for this as the request will get lost in all the other messages that go through the room. Messages can be starred and/or pinned, but that only works if there aren't many such messages.

Comment: @ChrisF: I meant a dedicated room for such requests.

Comment: @M.NightDemonbobby - then the problem becomes that the community team have to check that room (along with all the other rooms they check) and the moderators have to remember to go back to check on the results. Not all moderators have access to chat all of the time (e.g from work).